# Fazer um desenho conforme entrada do usuário

Tags: c

O exercício pede para que o programa receba um inteiro `n` e imprima um desenho de altura `2*n` da seguinte maneira:

```
\    *    /
 \  ***  /
  \*****/
   \***/
    \*/
    /*\
   /***\
  /*****\
 /  ***  \
/    *    \
```

Fiz o seguinte até o momento:

```
void arte(int n)
{
    int i, barrasE, aux, espacobarrasE, ebE, espaco;
    aux = n;

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(aux < n) //Espaços impressos antes das contra barras na parte superior.
        {
            espacobarrasE = n - aux;
            for(ebE = 0; ebE < espacobarrasE; ebE++)
                printf(" ");
        }
        for(barrasE = 1; barrasE <= aux; barrasE++) //Desenha as contra barras na diagonal na parte superior.
        {
            printf("\\");
            break;
        }
        for(espaco = 1; espaco < n; espaco++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        aux = aux - 1;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Mas isso só imprime as contra barras de cima e não sei como continuar. Gostaria de saber qual o melhor jeito de continuar.

Comment: só pra confirmar, nesse primeiro exemplo, n=5 correto ?

Comment: Sim, Rovann. n = 5 e foi impresso um desenho de altura 2n = 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Começando pela parte superior:

Qualquer linha pode ser formada a partir deste padrão: (`espaço`)(`\`)(`espaço`)(`*`)(`espaço`)(`/`)(`espaço`) e a questão fica em quantas vezes cada símbolo deve ser desenhado em cada linha.

Veja essa função:

```
void desenha(int qtd, char simbolo){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<qtd; i++)
        printf("%c", simbolo);
}
```

Nessa função você passa um número `qtd` e um símbolo e este símbolo será impresso `qtd` vezes na tela. Por exemplo `desenha(5, '*')`:

O resultado será: `*****`

A primeira linha do seu exemplo (`\    *    /`)pode ser representada da forma

(0,`espaço`)(1,`\`)(4,`espaço`)(1,`*`)(4,`espaço`)(1,`/`)(0,`espaço`)

e uma linha qualquer por

(n1,`espaço`)(n2,`\`)(n3,`espaço`)(n4,`*`)(n5,`espaço`)(n6,`/`)(n7,`espaço`)

como n2 e n6 sempre serão 1 e n1 sempre é igual a n7 e n3 sempre é igual a n5, podemos escrever de forma simplificada

(N1,`espaço`)(1,`\`)(N2,`espaço`)(N3,`*`)(N2,`espaço`)(1,`/`)(N1,`espaço`)

Agora basta apenas definir como será feito o cálculo de N1, N2 e N3 e conseguirá desenhar a parte superior. A inferior será feita facilmente depois, apenas invertendo a ordem do cálculo.

Um modo que eu usei para fazer o cálculo foi:

```
N1 = i;
N2 = n - 2*i -1;
N3 = n - 2*abs(i-(n/2));
```

Porém tente criar sua própria lógica para realizar o cálculo. Obs: na lógica que eu usei, quando um número par é passado para a função o desenho sai um pouco diferente, porém também não foi especificado como deveria ser, tente corrigir isso também.

Código completo:

```
void desenha(int qtd, char simbolo){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<qtd; i++)
        printf("%c", simbolo);
}


void arte(int n){
    int N1, N2, N3;
    int i;
    //Parte superior
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        N1 = i;
        N2 = n - 2*i -1;
        N3 = n - 2*abs(i-(n/2));

        desenha(N1, ' ');
        desenha(1, '\\');
        desenha(N2 , ' ');
        desenha(N3 , '*');
        desenha(N2, ' ');
        desenha(1, '/');
        printf("\n");
    }
    //Parte inferior
    for(i=n-1; i>=0; i--){
        N1 = i;
        N2 = n - 2*i -1;
        N3 = n - 2*abs(i-(n/2));

        desenha(N1, ' ');
        desenha(1, '/');
        desenha(N2 , ' ');
        desenha(N3 , '*');
        desenha(N2, ' ');
        desenha(1, '\\');
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    arte(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Valeu Lucas! Sua resposta me ajudou bastante.